# Java 8 Asynchronous IO Internals

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, nio

I am trying to understand how exactly the Async File IO (java.nio.AsyncFileChannel) in Java 8 works.

My specific question is, does the AsyncFileChannel internally uses a pool of threads and does a blocking wait OR uses system calls to let kernel notify when the IO task is finished. (I know there may be subtle variations per implementation, but what's the most widely used approach).

Also, I will be highly obliged if I can get reference to design/implementation docs for the nio package, specifically the AsyncIO part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It uses system calls.

Comment: This is implementation defined - but it uses async io internally.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin. So this means its using non blocking way of file io. Some thing that still doesn't add up is why the AsynchronousFileChannel.open (path) will create 25 threads when instantiated? Having such large thread pool generally indicates blocking threads. 

I apologize if my questions are naive. And thanks so much for helping me out with this.

Comment: No, it means it uses asynchronous 'way of file I/O', via system calls. If there are platforms which don't have it, it's obliged to fake it up with threads. 25 seems like a lot though.

Comment: @EJP thanks so much :). I verified this.